# Auto update related objects in Django

Tags: python, django

I have two models in django - "Project" and "Task". Tasks are assigned to projects with foreign key. I'm trying to make that so, when I update Project to 'done' in Project Update View, it automatically updates all the tasks asigned to this project to also be "done". So far i tried to write custom function in model but it didn't seem to work.
Here are my models:

```
STATUS = (
    (0, "ToDo"),
    (1, "Done"),
)

class Project(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=24, unique=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default = 0)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title

class Task(models.Model):
    
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.ForeignKey('tasktrack.Project', related_name='Tasks', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=24, unique=True)
    # author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name= 'tasks')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=48)
    created_on = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default = 0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title

    def update(self):
        self.updated_on = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def is_week_old(self):
        return (timezone.now() - self.created_on).days > 5
```

Project form class:

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model = Project
        fields = ('title', 'status')
        
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'textinputclass'}),
        }
```

and view

```
class ProjectEditView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    model = Project
    form_class = ProjectForm
    template_name = 'project_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('project_list')
```

Comment: I think based on your qsn you need signal to trigger update the task

Comment: check out signals of django, it pretty handy to check  and handle before  and after saving/creating/delete an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make the Project model related_name to the small letter in the Task model.

```
project = models.ForeignKey('tasktrack.Project', related_name='tasks', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Rather than defining custom functions in the model, you can do this by

1. Adding custom logic in your view
2. Using Django signal

Here, both approach has pros and cons. You can choose anyone who fulfills your requirements.

> Adding custom logic in your view

Update your **view** as:

```
class ProjectEditView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    model = Project
    form_class = ProjectForm
    template_name = 'project_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('project_list')
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = self.get_object()
        # since status is 0, 1 not comparing like status == 1
        if form.cleaned_data.get('status'):
            obj.tasks.update(status=1)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

> Using [Django signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/)

*update your models*

```
class Project(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=24, unique=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default = 0)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title

    @receiver(post_save, sender=Project)
    def update_tasks(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        # since status is 0, 1 not comparing like status == 1
        if instance.status:
            instance.tasks.update(status=1)
```